# how to convert RealmSwift List to Results?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-cocoa

I am using a Realm `List/Results` as my dataSource for a `UITableView`. At some point I assign a list to it. like:

```
var dataSource:List<SomeObject>! // Or >> Results<SomeObject>!
let aRealmObject =  realm.objectForPrimaryKey(SomeObject.self, key: objectId) 
dataSource = aRealmObject.someList // dataSource should be List
```

Then I have a filter on this list If the user changed the filter dates, I do like this:

```
dataSource = dataSource.filter("FILTER THE DATES",newDates) // dataSource should be Results
```

But the line above causes an error as the return type of `filter` is a `Results` object and `aRealmObject.someList` is a List.

What is the best way to deal with this situation?

- make dataSource as a `List` and convert the `Results` object to `List`? How??
- make dataSource as a `Results` and convert the `List` to `Results`? How??
- Or may be you have a better way of doing it, Please share it with me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `List` and `Results` (as well as `LinkingObjects`) can be converted into an [`AnyRealmCollection`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/AnyRealmCollection.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift18AnyRealmCollectioncuRd__S_19RealmCollectionTypexzwd__7ElementrFqd__GS0_x_) type. I think this is probably the best way to standardize all of Realm's array-type types:

```
var dataSource:AnyRealmCollection!
let aRealmObject = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(SomeObject.self, key: objectId) 
dataSource = AnyRealmCollection(aRealmObject.someList)
```

Answer (score 14):

I have found A simple way to convert `List` to `Results` making use if the filter method, it always returns `Results` object. Just gave it a true predicate.

```
   dataSource = aRealmObject.someList.filter("TRUEPREDICATE") //this is a Results object.
```

Comment: I worry that this will have an unnecessary overhead by iterating through and possibly faulting each object.

Comment: I agree That would be unnecessary work iterating the list, but I don't think it will be noticeable, not unless you have 500k records in your list.