# Generic collection for realm objects

Tags: swift, realm

We're finding that our project has lots of duplicated/boilerplate code surrounding collections of realm objects for basic list view controllers, and wondering if there's some generic container we can encapsulate them in.

It seems like `AnyRealmCollection` is vaguely related to that concept, and I found this [old/spuriously sourced link](http://www.tuicode.com/article/5625198629df802c2c69daf3) and this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203338/677620) in which it does basically exactly what I want, but that syntax definitely doesn't work anymore. My goal is basically the following (pardon my pseudocode)

```
class ParentController: UITableViewController {
  var dataSource: GenericRealmCollection!
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
  }
}

class ChildController: ParentController {
  func viewDidLoad() {
    dataSource = realm.objects(MyModel.self).filter(...)
  }
}
```

I'm guessing there's some swift type-erasure thing that i'm not fully understanding that will accommodate this, but I've been playing around with it most of the afternoon and haven't made much progress.

### Update 1

Looks like `AnyRealmCollection` definitely isn't what i'm looking forward based on [@kishikawa-katsumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733883/kishikawa-katsumi)'s explanation. As I mentioned in the comments, doing that forces class generics, which really limit interoperability with Obj-C. My hope is to completely erase the type (or at least get back to `Object`, then have helper functions for casting to the right type when I need the objects. It's looking like this may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

`AnyRealmCollection<T>` is used in the following manner.

```
class ParentController<T: Object>: UITableViewController {
    var dataSource: AnyRealmCollection<T>!
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
}

class ChildController: ParentController<MyModel> {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource = AnyRealmCollection(realm.objects(MyModel.self))
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, bummer, that doesn't accomplish what I'm hoping to do. I could do the same thing with Results<T>, but that forces me to use generic classes, which really hurts interop with obj-c. Cant do nice things like `extension ChildViewController: UITableViewDataSource { }`